# Internal error (java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException): C:\Users\Р’С–Рє

Tags: java, intellij-idea

While tryin` to build any project (even empty) in Intellij Idea, I get this error:

```
Internal error (java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException): C:\Users\Р’С–Рє
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\Р’С–Рє
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:89)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:509)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:690)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:797)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:783)
    at com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.ensureParentDirectoryExists(ResizeableMappedFile.java:181)
    at com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.<init>(ResizeableMappedFile.java:67)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.<init>(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:93)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumerator.createDefaultEnumerator(PersistentEnumerator.java:66)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentMapImpl.<init>(PersistentMapImpl.java:136)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentMapBuilder.buildImplementation(PersistentMapBuilder.java:62)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentMapBuilder.build(PersistentMapBuilder.java:44)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:39)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:54)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.createMap(AbstractStateStorage.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.<init>(AbstractStateStorage.java:29)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.FileTimestampStorage.<init>(FileTimestampStorage.java:27)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.ProjectStamps.<init>(ProjectStamps.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:97)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:311)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:162)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:218)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Please perform full project rebuild (Build | Rebuild Project)
```

It must be C:\Users\Вік instead of C:\Users\Р’С–Рє, but i don`t know how to make Intellij read it correctly

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Try to change the IDE [system](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#system-directory) and [configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory) directories to any path, without `C:\Users\Вік` in the name. If you have antivirus/firewall, try with them disabled or make sure to exclude the mentioned directories and the IDE installation from the scan.

Answer (score 0):

The access to write or read from this directory has been denied by your computer while mishandling a program or another app.
Close all opened projects from Intellij and close all running applications on your computer.
Make sure all of them are well closed then restart your PC. This should solve the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It said that you dont have permission to execute action on that path. Try to set your permission, example in linux:

```
chmod -R 777 YOUR_APTH
```

In window, you can try this:
https://v2cloud.com/tutorials/how-to-change-folder-permissions-on-windows

Comment: The OP is using Windows, which doesn't have chmod.

Comment: Sorry, i dint notice that, will updated my answers.